# The MySQL adapter 'mysql' is not available and session Warnings

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, xampp

I am getting the following errors:

> Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysql' is not
>   available.
>
> Warning: session_write_close(): Cannot call session save
>   handler in a recursive manner in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\RCUB_praveen_Backup\libraries\joomla\session\session.php
>   on line 681
>
> Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using
>   user defined save handler. (session.save_path: C:\xampp\tmp) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\RCUB_praveen_Backup\libraries\joomla\session\session.php
>   on line 681

I have uploaded database successfully and I use XAMPP v3.2.2

Comment: Have you Googled around for these error messages?  Found any clues?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150296/cant-make-custom-session-save-handler-workno-registered-method-called-in-cent  Do we get any more details about your server environment?  PHP version, MyQL version, phpinfo, (did you restart after installing it)?

Answer (score 1):

In you configuration.php file, change the database driver from `mysql` to `mysqli`. The `mysql` database driver is now obsolete and is no longer bundled with PHP by default.